# Xcode workspaces - how to properly save new versions/backup?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, xcode-workspace

Im not sure this is the right place for this but I need an answer - in the past I have always saved backups (so I can revert back if I break something) of my Xcode projects by copy-pasting the project folder with the project tests/files inside (image below) and naming it a new version (i,e Project 1, project 2, so on):

[image]

This has worked well and in the past Ive been able to simply delete a screwed up version and open a past one and the code will be as I left it.

I have now started incorporating pods into my project so I am using the workspace instead of the Xcode project. This now brings in the issue of build "schemes" which appear in the upper left corner.

Not always, but sometimes after copy-pasting I will go back to a previous version and the code has "carried over" from the latest version/scheme. I don't really understand what a scheme is or if this is the problem but it has caused major problems at times.

When using the workspace, how does one properly save backups/new versions to go back to?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need a source control tool, the most used [Source Control Management](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Source_control_management&redirect=no) tool is called git. It's what a lot of people use, and you may have heard of GitHub - which is centered around git.

I'd recommend starting by going through this website: https://try.github.io/

Comment: Ive used git and Ive tried with this but as soon as I pull down a past version and try to run it it just runs code from the newest altered version

Comment: You should follow the try git tutorial, the command to look at older versions is `git checkout`.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, you should definitely get acquainted with git.  And the good news is that about a year after this question was asked, with the release of Xcode 9 (and with all subsequent versions since then), git is built right into Xcode.  When you create a project, on the screen where you select the folder you would like to save the project to, you will see a check box, as in this screenshot:

[image]

Always enable this (i.e., check the box), and you will never again need to manually save versions of your project to separate folders, as you outlined.

Cheers!